# What are all the CSS3 properties that accept URLs (or URIs)?

Tags: css

I mean properties like `background-image`, which can be written as

```
 background-image: url(www.example.com/coolbackground.jpg);
```

So far, my list includes:

`@fontface:src`

`@import`

`attr`

`background`

`background-image`

`border-image`

`border-image-source`

`content`

`list-style-image`

`mask-image`

I am sure there are others that I am missing.  Anyone have suggestions?  I'll add them to the list as they are posted.

Comment: `content` accepts URL (as any other string, so I'd add that one too)

Comment: If I may ask... why you need this?

Comment: Sure.  I'm working on a library called [domJSON](https://github.com/azaslavsky/domJSON), which converts DOM trees into JSON objects and vice versa.  One thing it does is get a node's computed style, and, for fields where URLs are possible values, convert them from relative paths to absolute ones if necessary.  I'm just trying to get an exhaustive list of fields to check, rather than running the check on every single style property (ex: `margin-top` can't possibly contain a relative URL, so there is no point in checking it for conversion).

Comment: Cool! This seems more to a ***Community Wiki*** than a question that searches for a *Correct Answer* :)

Comment: Ah, maybe that's true.  Is there a way to easily move it?  I guess technically there is a correct answer (the complete list of all properties that accept URLs), but it might be hard to find.  I've never used the community wiki before, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Josh already converted [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27790977/383904) to *Wiki* so everyone (including everyone :) ) is welcome to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)
- [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)
- [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)
- [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)
- [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)
- [`list-style-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image)
- [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `attr` and `@import`.  I'll add them to the list.

Comment: You *may* be interested in [this draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/) too..